# Convert extended ASCII characters to Latin1

Tags: c++, ascii

I can find different values of same ASCII characters at the below links:

1.http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/
   **(Extended ASCII in non-latin format)**

2.https://www.ascii-code.com/
   **(shows Extended Ascii in Latin1 format)**

In the first link i can see the value of á (a with acute accent) = 160,
In the second link value of á (a with acute accent) = 225

similary there is a Random Difference between each values ranging from 128-255.

I have a **C++** application where i am getting the ASCII value in Non-Latin Format (1), which i need to Output in Latin Value (2). Is there any formula which could be helpful? Please help. Thanks

Comment: The "formula" is a lookup table.  Give me `x`, and my table gives you back `y`.

Comment: what i look here is a "logical conversion", and not hard-coded values

Comment: You could try `data.decode('cp437').encode('latin1')`. However, there are many versions of extended ascii, so there is no guarantee that this will work.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Comment: is there something like that in C++ ?

Comment: @user2008585. Why have you got the python tag on your question?

Comment: Is this question about C++ or Python?

Comment: @user2008585 Well, there's [`libiconv`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/).

Comment: It seems a bit strange that you've identified the character sets and encodings that you need to deal with by random website rather than by name. Are you sure you've picked the right two? For "á", there are also many character encodings where the character code is  69, 97, 111, or 135. For 225, there are iso-8859-2,iso-8859-1,iso-8859-9,windows-1258,iso-8859-1,iso-8859-2,iso-8859-3,iso-8859-4,iso-8859-9,iso-8859-15. For 160, there are IBM437,ibm850,ibm852,ibm857,IBM00858,IBM860,ibm861,DOS-862,IBM865,x-Europa. And that only includes the ones in my programming environment.

Answer (score 0):

The first table looks like the codepage 437 you can found on Windows.

If you have a string encoded with this codepage, you can decode it like this:

```
text = b"your\xa0text".decode("cp437")
```

You get: 'yourátext'

To convert it to ISO Latin1, you can write:

```
latin1 = text.encode("Latin1"). # or "8859-1"
```

You get the bytes string: b'your\xe1text'

Notice: some characters won't convert from cp437 to Latin1.

Comment: Which particular language is this? Python?

Comment: Yes, it's Python.

Comment: In C/C++ on Windows, you can use the Win32 API `MultiByteToWideChar()` and `WideCharToMultiByte()` functions to convert data between codepages. On other platforms (or on Windows, too), use a dedicated C library for Unicode conversions, like ICONV or ICU.